# CiviCRM 5.69.2 update - now each contact link in relationshsips tab opens a new browser tab - how can we disable _blank

Tags: relationships

We updated CiviCRM to 5.69.2 and now every time we click a contact under relationships (active), it loads a new browser tab.  Some people may like that feature, but it is difficult for us.  We don't see how/where to disable it or change it.  In our instance, this version now displays a message

*"Permissioned Relationships: This contact can be viewed by the other. This contact can be viewed and edited by the other."*

Also new to us, in relationships tab view, along with an icon dropdown 2 options, edit relationships in formbuilder plus edit contact summary relationships in searchkit.

We've been looking through admin menu, configuration, display preferences, etc. to no avail.  Any ideas? Please share.

Comment: Do you have the admin ui extension enabled?

Comment: At first we did not have admin ui plugin on wordpress activated.  activating it seemed to make no difference, so it is deactivated once more.

Comment: I can replicate the opening in new tabs too. Do non-admins see this message?
"an icon dropdown 2 options, edit relationships in formbuilder plus edit contact summary relationships in searchkit."

Answer (score 2):

I see what you mean.  That tab was replaced in core (rather than AdminUI). The links are configured to be pop-ups but are loading as new tabs.  The same problem is occurring in other places with pop-ups so something has broken. Hopefully that will be fixed very soon.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this issue. I've opened a ticket with a fix: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29039

Update: PR has been merged & fix will be released with v5.70.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Will track...